# Why is this gcloud compute copy-files producing an error message?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

When I execute the command

> gcloud compute copy-files "C:\Users\fName lName\Desktop\testtext.txt"
>   instancename:test.txt --zone europe-west1-a

I receive the error: `"All sources must be local files when the destination is remote."`.

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Strange, it's working for me in Linux. Try this instead: gcloud compute copy-files "C:\Users\fName lName\Desktop\testtext.txt" instancename: --zone europe-west1-a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks asking this!  This appears to be a bug in gcloud that we're now tracking.  The issue is that `gcloud compute copy-files` is interpreting the colon in `C:\Users\fNam...` as a part of a remote path.  As suggested by George's answer, the work around is to avoid local paths containing the colon character.

Answer (score 23):

In order to copy the file testtext.txt that you are specifying, you need to be in the path where that file is and specify its name while copying not the path.

**Example:** from your command line lets suppose you are in this path:

> C:\Users\fName lName\Desktop\

Your command should be the following:

```
gcloud compute copy-files --zone europe-west1-b testtext.txt instancename:/PATH_where_you_want_the_file
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a huge help. Looking forward to having the workaround be put into place!

Comment: George - update the answer to use scp? I get: Please use `gcloud compute scp` instead.  Note that `gcloud compute scp` does not have recursive copy on by default.

Answer (score 8):

For example, to copy a remote directory to your local host, run:

```
   gcloud compute copy-files \
      my-instance:~/remote-dir \
      ~/local-dir \
      --zone us-central1-a
```

In the above example, “/remote-dir” from “my-instance” is copied into the “/local-dir” directory.
Conversely, files from your local computer can be copied to a virtual machine:

```
gcloud compute copy-files \
    ~/my-local-file-1 \
    ~/my-local-file-2 \
    my-instance:~/remote-destination \
    --zone us-central1-a
```

Here's a real live example for you:

#### Copy a remote file directory to your local host, run:

```
gcloud compute copy-files \
      instance-4:~/ \
      ~/Desktop/project/scripts/step/folder/* \
      --zone asia-east1-a \
      --project 911911911911911 \
```

#### All files from your local computer can be copied to a virtual machine:

```
gcloud compute copy-files \
    ~/Desktop/project/scripts/step/folder/* \
    instance-3:~/ \
    --zone asia-east1-a \
    --project 911911911911911 \
```

Answer (score 4):

instead of "C:\Users\fName lName\Desktop\testtext.txt"
use "\Users\fName lName\Desktop\testtext.txt" .
That worked for me