# gcloud compute scp error: All sources must be local files

Tags: copy, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, scp

I tried to copy file from my google cloud instance to local machine with the following command:

```
gcloud compute scp nlp-2:to_test.txt C:\Temp
```

And got back the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) All sources must be local files when destination is remote.  Got sources: [nlp-2:to_test.txt], destination: 
C:Temp
```

What is exactly wrong? I am confident that the same command worked like 2 days ago.

Update: I am connecting to Ubuntu 16.04 (google instance) from Win 7 (local machine)

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it has to do with [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742867/why-is-this-gcloud-compute-copy-files-producing-an-error-message).

Answer (score 2):

In order to resolve copying files to the instance, I had to create a path in `D:` (in your case can be `C:`) the same as the one represented by `~` in the ubuntu instance (`/home/example_name/`) and put the files to copy in that windows directory:

```
sudo gcloud beta compute scp --project="projectname" --zone="zonename" ~/Filename.zip instancename:~/
```

The reason is because the console scp does not support `:`

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried to replicate the issue running the following code on a Google Cloud SDK Shell from a machine with Windows Server 2008 R2:

```
gcloud compute scp instance-1:/home/username/file C:\Users\username\file2
```

where instance-1 is a Debian 4.9.51-1 and **I have been able to copy the file**.

Therefore I think you misspelled something writing the command (also because you wrote that it was working for you as well some days ago) or I didn't understand correctly your configuration.
If this is the case an you provide some information more editing the question?

**EDIT**

I tested as well to do SCP between Debian machine having "weird" names and I **have been always able to copy the files** both from a remote location and to a remote location:

```
gcloud compute scp instance-1:/paolo '/C:\\Temp'
```

and

```
gcloud compute scp instance-2:'/C:\\Temp' .
```

> Note despite the weird notation that C:\Temp is a file stored in a Linux instance

Comment: Thank you for reply. My copy command is fairly simple. If I misspelled something I would get error about path that does not exist. Also I am connecting to Ubuntu 16.04 (google instance) from Win 7 (local machine)

Comment: it is really weird then, basically we had the very same command that had been interpreted in two different ways. Which is the version of the Cloud SDK you are using? You can try to update the components and retry  `gcloud components update` Mine is "Google Cloud SDK 182.0.0"

Comment: How did it go this time?

Comment: @GalloCedrone my cloud VM is linux and my local machine is Windows 10 with your suggestion, I am getting following error

Comment: gcloud compute copy-files assignment1:~/assignment1/requirements.txt C:\temp
WARNING: `gcloud compute copy-files` is deprecated.  Please use `gcloud compute scp` instead.  Note that `gcloud compute scp` does not have recursive copy on by default.  To turn on recursion, use the `--recurse` flag.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) All sources must be local files when destination is remote.  Got sources: [assignment1:~/assignment1/requirements.txt], destination: C:temp

Comment: What if you use `gcloud compute scp assignment1:~/assignment1/requirements.txt C:\temp`? Are you running them on a windows machine? @JumabekAlikhanov

Comment: How can we enable multiprocessing during copying these files to the local.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to use as it worked for me:

in my case every file was in the folder jupyter!

```
gcloud beta compute scp --project "project_name" --zone "zone_name" instance_name:~jupyter/file_name /home/Downloads
```